# How to ensure that we write to a row after a read and ensure that nothing has changed in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, locking

Quick question:

Imagine this scenario:

```
if !order.has_not_refunded?
    order.refund! (has stuff like Stripe.refund, etc.)
end
```

I want to make sure that after I make the check that the order has refunded, I want to refund and make sure that nothing else has refunded the order yet. It's possible that in between the check and the refund, some other process could have refunded the order. How do I ensure that while reading the row, nothing else can write to the row? Is this what I even want? If so, what's the best way to do this? Does Rails have anything built in to prevent this?